# Spring Boot Keycloak - How to get a list of roles assigned to a user?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest, keycloak

I am trying to get a list of roles assigned to a particular user from a Spring Boot application secured with keycloak.

I have declared an `AccessToken` bean in the `KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` configuration class as follows:

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class)
    public class KeycloakSecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

//other config code

        @Bean
        @Scope(scopeName = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
        public AccessToken accessToken() {
            HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
            return ((KeycloakSecurityContext) ((KeycloakAuthenticationToken) request.getUserPrincipal()).getCredentials()).getToken();
        }

    }
```

Now I can autowire the `AccessToken` in the controller and I am able to get the information like ID and username but how do I get the list of roles assigned to the user using the `AccessToken`?

Answer (score 5):

for resource role mapping use

```
AccessToken.Access access = accessToken.getResourceAccess(clientId);
     Set<String> roles = access.getRoles();
```

for realm role mappings use

```
AccessToken.Access access = accessToken.getRealmAccess();
 Set<String> roles = access.getRoles();
```

Comment: Is it possible to have a full example of SecurityConfig & another class e.g. controller where this AccessToken is used?